# Работа с двумя базами в Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, phpmyadmin

Задача состоит в том, чтобы разделить всех пользователей приложения на две группы, скажем, на "русских" и "американцев" с двумя отдельными базами данных. В зависимости от того, к какой группе пренадлежит юзер, выводить данные с соответствующей базы. Cама группа определяется в таблице `users` для каждого пользователя отдельно.

В файле `config/database.php` я добавил новое подключение для второй базы данных.

Все данные для пользователя выводятся через контроллеры. Я попытался использовать проверку на принадлежность к группе и возвращать данные через `DB::connection`, но внутри контроллера это не работает. `DB::`определяется как контроллер, который не инициализирован.

Существет ли способ в момент авторизации пользователя определить его группу и в зависимости от нее сразу установить нужное подключение к нужной базе данных?
Прочитал, что это, кажется, можно реализовать через IoC, но я не имею представления, каким образом это делается.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: А зачем вам разные БД, почему нельзя использовать разные таблицы, к примеру?

Comment: А зачем вам разные таблицы, почему нельзя использовать колонку идентификации, к примеру?

Comment: Такие требования, увы